# Simple search error when no results found

Tags: simple-search

I'm using simple search with EE 5.2.1. Searches work fine when there is a matching result, but I get the following error when no results are found:

Warning
array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
ee/EllisLab/Addons/search/mod.search.php, line 1147

Severity: E_WARNING
Warning
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
ee/EllisLab/Addons/search/mod.search.php, line 1147

Severity: E_WARNING
Warning
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:120)
ee/legacy/libraries/Functions.php, line 393

Severity: E_WARNING

Comment: did you specify a no results page? sounds like it's expecting results to be there

Comment: Yes, I did specify a no results page.

Answer (score 1):

I updated EE to 5.3.0 and it fixed the issue.